# Incorrect date format in elasticsearch result

Tags: elasticsearch

My document looks as following:

```
{
   'time'   : <timestamp_with_millis>,
   'amount' : <int>
}
```

I am doing this query:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "articles_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "time",
                "interval" : "1M",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I get:

```
"articles_over_time": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss1451606400000",
          "key": 1451606400000,
          "doc_count": 63
        }
      ]
    }
```

Can somebody explain me why the key is at the end of `key_as_string` value and the timestamp is not formatted?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is "expected". The `format` parameter in the [`date_histogram` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_keys) only works with fields specifically mapped with the `date` type in the mapping.

In your case, the value is a `long` and that explains why the `key_as_string` gets formatted that way. If you change your field mapping from `long` to `date` it will work as expected.

The following issue will shed some light on this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8007

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try putting interval as "1m" instead of "1M" I am afraid that its counting capital M as Month.